# Matlab: initialize empty array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I need to create an empty array of matrices, and after fill it with matrices of the same size.

I have made a little script to explain:

```
result = [];

for i = 0: 4;
    M = i * ones(5,5); % create matrice
    result = [result,M];  % this would have to append M to results
end
```

Here result is a matrix of size `5*25` and I need  an array of matrices `5*5*4`.

I have been researched but I only found this line: `result = [result(1),M];`

Comment: Maybe just a typo, but do you not want `result = [result,M];`. But I guess there might be other problem in terms of dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `[]` implicitly concatenates values horizontally (the second dimension). In your case, you want to concatenate them along the *third* dimension so you could use [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html).

```
result = cat(3, result, M);
```

But a better way to do it would be to actually pre-allocate your `result` array using `zeros`

```
result = zeros(5, 5, 4);
```

And then within your loop fill each "slice" of the 3D array with the values.

```
for k = 0:4
    M = k * ones(5,5);
    result(:,:,k+1) = M;
end
```